# Calling Workflows from Scheduler

Tags: google-workflows

I have following schedule config:

[image]

And SA has following roles:
[image]

But getting error that it is not able to authenticate. Any thoughts what could be issue?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For googleapis.com endpoints, you want [OAuth rather than OIDC authentication](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth). Note you can [add Scheduler triggers in the Workflows UI](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/schedule-workflow), which is somewhat simpler, as it sets these values for you, and also formats arguments as required.

Comment: Unfortunately, workflows for schedule trigger is not yet supported by terraform resource.  I switched to `OAuth` - and getting this now `status:"INVALID_ARGUMENT"` .

Comment: I figured why `INVALID_ARGUMENT`.   After playing with https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/executions/rest/v1/projects.locations.workflows.executions.  Switching to OAuth was a key!  Thanks Kris!

Comment: So weird... now fixing `INVALID_ARGUMENT` issue start getting issue with `PERMISSION_DENIED` .

Comment: Most commonly, `PERMISSION_DENIED` would mean the service account lacks the `Workflows Invoker` permission, but you clearly show your SA has that. Is the OAuth scope blank or set to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`?

Comment: It is defaulting to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`.  I will open a case with Google support tomorrow.